# How to extract values from BehaviouralSubject in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I created an Account Service, for my angular application, and it handles the Login and logout. and this works perfectly. But I am having an issue, I used BehaviourSubject Observables to render the variables.

I am trying to retrieve the loginstatus value, and the username string on the component using the service, but the observable is returning an object, and I am having problems extracting the string out of the object. How can I extract variable types from Behavioursubject observables?

The Account Service...

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, Subject, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Injectable({ 
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AccountService {
  

  private baseUrlLogin:string = "/api/account/login";

  private loginStatus = new BehaviorSubject<boolean> 
  (this.checkLoginStatus());  
  private userName = new BehaviorSubject<string> localStorage.getItem['username']);

  constructor(
    private http:HttpClient, 
    private router: Router
  ){}

  login(username:string, password:string){
    return this.http.post<any>(this.baseUrlLogin,{username, password}).pipe(
               map(result => {
                  if(result && result.token){
                      localStorage.setItem('loginStatus', '1'); 
                      localStorage.setItem('username', result.username),

                  }
                  return result;
                  
               })
           );

  }

  logout(){
    this.loginStatus.next(false);
    localStorage.setItem('loginStatus', '0');  
    localStorage.removeItem('username'),
    localStorage.clear();

    //now redirect to the login page... 
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    console.log("logged out successfully...");
  }

   
  get isLoggedIn(){
    return this.loginStatus.asObservable(); 
  }

  get currentUserName(){
    return this.userName.asObservable();  
  }

}
```

The Component Using the Service

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AccountService } from 'src/app/services/account.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  pgtitle:string = "SCB Dashboard";

  loginStatus$ : Observable<boolean>;
  username$ : Observable<string>;

  constructor(
    private acc:AccountService
  ){}

  ngOnInit() {
   this.loginStatus$ = this.acc.isLoggedIn;
   this.username$ = this.acc.currentUserName;
   

   console.log(this.loginStatus$);  //here it ruturns an object
   console.log(this.username$);   //and here too... 

  }

}
```

The console.log() returns an object, but how do I retrieve the variables, and work with them in the controller, since they are of type observable?

Comment: `this.username$.subscribe(value => { console.log(value) });`

Comment: this.loginStatus$.getValue() and this.username$.getValue() would do the trick or just this.loginStatus$.value and this.username$.value

Comment: Yes, this should work. Here a link to the corresponding documentation:
https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md#rxbehaviorsubjectprototypegetvalue

Answer (score 1):

Rxjs BehaviourSubject has an asObservable() method, you can generate your observable from it

```
let sourceSubject = new BehaviourSubject();
let source$ = sourceSubject.asObservable();

source$.subscribe(result => // Your data)

// Update the BehaviourSubject

sourceSubject.next(newValue);
```

Comment: Behavior subjects are already observables, no need to create a new observable with asObservable

Comment: If this code is in a service, it would be good practice to use code such as this. Then mark the Subject/BehaviorSubject as private and the Observable public so that component code can access the Observable, but not directly inject information into the stream.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `subscribe` to the observable to get the value out of it:

```
this.loginStatus$.subscribe(value => {
   console.log(value); // access value
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
get isLoggedIn(){
  return this.loginStatus.value; 
}

get currentUserName(){
  return this.userName.value;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should also work:

```
  ngOnInit() {
   this.loginStatus$ = this.acc.isLoggedIn.pipe(
     tap(status => console.log(status))
   );
   this.username$ = this.acc.currentUserName.pipe(
     tap(userName => console.log(userName))
   );

  }
```

Assuming that you subscribed somewhere, such as with an async pipe.